# querying for "workweek" in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a formula from MS Excel 2007 which returns the workweek of a certain date within a certain month.

```
B1 = IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2,1)<>1,A2=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1)),A2-WEEKDAY(A2,1)+7,IF(MONTH(A2)<>MONTH(A2-WEEKDAY(A2,1)+7),EOMONTH(A2,0),A2-WEEKDAY(A2,1)+7))
```

where A1 = `11/2012` and B1 = `1/7/2012`

I'd like to use this formula in MS Access and will return the same value. I'd tried to formulate a query but it won't work.

The field name of column A1 is [rdate] and column B1's field name is [we_date].

Answer (score 4):

Don't calculate, query. See:

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

> A calendar table can make it much
>   easier to develop solutions around any
>   business model which involves dates.
>   Last I checked, this encompasses
>   pretty much any business model you can
>   think of, to some degree.    Constant
>   problems that end up requiring
>   verbose, complicated and inefficient
>   methods include the following
>   questions:
>
> - How many business days between x and y?
> - What are all of the dates between the second Tuesday of March and the first Friday in April?
> - On what date should I expect this shipment to arrive?
> - What were the dates of all the Fridays in this quarter?
> - ...