# Query To Obtain More Information Than Is Available In A Table And Use Previous Data If No Match Found

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of prices for various securities (in this case, securities are S1 and S2 with monthly prices, though S1 also has a mid-month price in March)

Table Name:  Prices

```
Name     Date      Price                       
 S1    1/31/2013     110 
 S2    1/31/2013      85
 S1    2/28/2013     120
 S2    2/28/2013      84
 S1    3/15/2013     115
 S1    3/31/2013     125
 S2    3/31/2013      86
```

Is it possible to generate a query that will include all days a specified range, sorted by security, but utilize that security's most recently dated price if a price for that date is unavailable?

E.g.

```
Name     Date      Price                       
 S1    2/27/2013    110 
 S1    2/28/2013    120
 S1    3/01/2013    120
 S1    3/02/2013    120
 S1    3/03/2013    120
      etc. . . . 
 S1    3/15/2013    115
 S1    3/16/2013    115
     etc. . . . 
 S1    3/30/2013    115
 S1    3/31/2013    125
```

In the above instance, a full month's worth of prices for S1 from Feb 27 to Mar 31 would show prices ranging from 110-125 depending upon the date.

Comment: What is the data source for the range of dates you look up ... is it another table?  Or is this question about how to generate a list of dates with a query?

Comment: At this point I was thinking a query criteria with >[Start Date] and <=[End Date] though I'm not wedded to any one way.
If the proffered solution requires a table of dates to be created first, I'd be okay with that too.  
Basically it comes down to generating a complete list of securities with prices for every date even if the date does not have a price (in which case it would use the most recent price).  The database has a lot of securities priced monthly, so this query would help sort each security and price them on every date.  
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hurdle is to get a row for each date in your selected date range, including those dates which are not present in the `Prices` table.  That task is easy with a calendar table.  See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095557/77335) for a discussion of how such a table can be useful.  The following query is based on my `tblCalendar`; you can find code to create and load your own at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303628/77335).

```sql
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT c.the_date
FROM tblCalendar AS c
WHERE c.the_date Between [Start Date] And [End Date];
```

Then you can [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join) that query with a subquery which returns unique security names from `Prices` to give you one row for each combination of security name and date.  (If you have another table which contains the unique security names, use that in place of the subquery.)

```sql
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT
    c.the_date,
    sub.Name
FROM
    tblCalendar AS c,
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
        FROM Prices
    ) AS sub
WHERE c.the_date Between [Start Date] And [End Date];
```

With that second query working, the final piece is to include a correlated subquery to fetch the security `Price` from the most recent `Prices.Date` which was on or before `the_date`.  To make the SQL of the final query easier to write, I will assume you saved the previous query as *qryBase*.

```sql
SELECT
    b.the_date,
    b.Name,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 p.Price
        FROM Prices AS p
        WHERE
                p.Date <= c.the_date
            AND p.Name = b.Name
        ORDER BY p.Date DESC
    ) AS current_price
FROM qryBase AS b
WHERE b.the_date Between [Start Date] And [End Date]
ORDER BY b.Name, b.the_date;
```

Beware, if your `Prices` table can include more than one row for a given security on the same date, the correlated subquery will break because `TOP` returns ties.  If that can happen, we will need to know which `Price` to select for that security/date combination.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the feedback.  I was uncertain whether I had explained all that clearly enough.  I just now added a link which explains cross join.  Too late for you, but someone else may benefit.  :-)