# Duplicate each row pulled in and add an extra field counting up one day between a given start and end date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm using Microsoft Access and I want to create a query that duplicates each row pulled in from a table with an extra field added on counting up one day between a given start and end date.

So if there's 4 days between the start and end date there's 4 duplicate rows returned for each record with only difference being the added date field counting up 1 day.

Is this actually possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is fairly easy if you have a calendar table which includes a row for each date you need.  (See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095557/77335) for other reasons why a calendar table can be useful.)  Without such a table, this task is not practical with Access SQL.

Using my [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296078/using-start-date-and-end-date-in-access-query/9303628#9303628) and this sample data in *YourTable* ...

```
fld1 start_date end_date
---- ---------- ----------
a    12/26/2013 12/26/2013
b    12/27/2014 12/28/2014
c      1/1/2014   1/3/2014
d      1/4/2014   1/1/2014
```

... the query below gave me this output.

```
fld1 start_date end_date   added_date
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
a    12/26/2013 12/26/2013 12/26/2013
b    12/27/2014 12/28/2014 12/27/2014
b    12/27/2014 12/28/2014 12/28/2014
c      1/1/2014   1/3/2014   1/1/2014
c      1/1/2014   1/3/2014   1/2/2014
c      1/1/2014   1/3/2014   1/3/2014
```

Notice the *"d"* row was not included in the output because `end_date` was earlier than `start_date` in that row.  You can include a table-level validation rule to enforce the requirement that `start_date` <= `end_date` in every row.

```sql
SELECT
    y.fld1,
    y.start_date,
    y.end_date,
    c.the_date AS added_date
FROM
    tblCalendar AS c
    INNER JOIN YourTable AS y
    ON
            c.the_date >= y.start_date
        AND c.the_date <= y.end_date
ORDER BY
    y.fld1,
    c.the_date;
```